# Hotspot incorrect in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

The hotspot drawn around the portfolio image at the start-page is incorrectly rendered in IE but no other browsers. The issue is also just this hotspot, all the other are still ok.

Any idea why? site here: http://developed-web.com/

**EDIT:** Fixed it, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the coords around a bit and re-saved. Don't know what the problem was but it works now.

Comment: Well that explains why I couldn't spot a single difference between IE10, IE9 en Chrome.

Comment: Tried to be quick about it, sorry!